# Unit tests that need UI input?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, xcode-ui-testing

I know that unit tests aren't supposed to deal with the UI, and that UI tests shouldn't involve testing the model, such as whether testing a value is nil or not.

But what about when the model requires user interaction that, as far as I know, can't be mocked?

(Okay I'm sure that if I were more experienced I could find that it can be mocked, so you can take the question as "I know it's not quite right but how can I do this without complicated mocking?")

I'm implementing Braintree Payments in my iOS app. Making a payment involves getting user info from my app, sending it to the server for a token, and when the token is returned, presenting a modal view controller for the user to select the payment method. This view controller is part of Braintree's API not part of my code, so I just get its return values, and then pass information about the payment method back to the server to complete the transaction.

I started to write iOS Unit tests for my `PaymentsHandler` model and then immediately remembered that it would present this controller.

So, besides looking into the Braintree API to see how I can generate the payment method info some other way (which would sort of defeat the point of testing my implementation anyway), how do I test this? Besides by hand of course!

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to test something that doesn't need testing. You don't need to test Braintree's code (neither the server interaction nor their view controller), so this _can_ be mocked because all that needs testing is _your_ code.

Comment: But I need to test that I've constructed my code right to pass around the results to and from Braintree's code. So I need to get the data that their view controller returns, and I need to interact with that view controller. No?

Comment: No. I mean, I don't know this API, so I can't speak definitively, but it seems to me that what you just described is what mocking _is_. This is not your class and not your code, so you can't test it and you don't want to, and you don't need to involve it in your test. You _know_ the kind of data their view controller returns, so there is no need to _run_ their view controller. You therefore supply something _else_ your code can interact with using the same API, supplying sample data to test your code against.